# 3 condicionales en pandas falla

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones

tengo las siguientes condiciones para una nueva columna en pandas:

```
condiciones=[(df['EMA']+df['EMA']*0.02<=df['Close']),(df['EMA']-df['EMA']*0.02>=df['Close']),(df['EMA']+df['EMA']*0.02>df['Close'] & df['EMA']-df['EMA']*0.02<=df['Close'])]
```

dond veo si el precio de un activo es diferente un 2%, tanto haca abajo o hacia arriba, las dos condiciones funcionan sin problemas, pero cuando pongo la ultima, que me revisa si el precio esta en ese rango me da el error siguiente:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'
```

Podrian indicarme que esta mal y como corregirlo? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Agrega paréntesis para separar cada condición

Comment: seria solo para organizar(costumbre que debo de hacer, gracias) pero sigue igual

Comment: Expandiendo lo que dijo HeytalePazguato: En realidad, este simbolo & está pensado para funcionar como un operador bit a bit, no como un and. Por esa razón, los operadores de comparación tienen mayor prioridad que este. Para evitar este problema, tenés que encerrar cada comparación entre parentesis. Por ejemplo (a == 1) & (b < 2). Eso es una forma de decirle a Python "esto tiene mayor prioridad"

Comment: gracias a los dos, en especial a @DanteS. por su explicacion detallada , disculpen mi ignorancia

Comment: No pasa nada y de nada c: Aquí no te juzgamos por tu ignorancia. Además, con el tiempo iras aprendiendo, nadie nace sabiendo :)

Comment: Y lo más importante es que hiciste una pregunta mostrando lo que has intentado, esas son las preguntas que merecen responderse. Una disculpa por no poder explicar más, estaba viajando y tuve que hacer un comentario rápido. Siempre que tengas una pregunta agrega lo que has intentado aunque no funcione y seguro alguien te va ayudar. El problema quedó resuelto con la explicación de Dante?

Comment: igual te agradezco, el solo la intencion vale mucho y de verdad te agradezco